# How to refactor async method to include await operators?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, mongodb-.net-driver

I've added an async Task that assigns a list to a new Bson document using [MongoDB.Net driver](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/). I get a warning on the method, that says I should add await operators to the API calls.

So what I've tried is, adding an `await` to the API call, but it gives me an error:

> Error 9   Cannot await
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I understand that I can't await the list type but not sure where else to place the operator. I was thinking that the Find call could be refactored into a Task and then assign customers to the result of that.

The customers list is of Type for reference.

Does anyone know how should I be adding the await operator to the API call?

This is where I've added the await operator on the method:

```
public async Task LoadDb()
{
    var customerCollection = StartConnection();
    try
    {
        customers = await customerCollection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }
    catch (MongoException ex)
    {
        //Log exception here:
        MessageBox.Show("A connection error occurred: " + ex.Message, "Connection Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    }
}
```

And this is the `StartConnection()` that the customerCollection comes from:

```
public IMongoCollection<CustomerModel> StartConnection()
{
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var database = client.GetDatabase("orders");
    //Get a handle on the customers collection:
    var collection = database.GetCollection<CustomerModel>("customers");
    return collection;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code:

```
customers = await customerCollection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

should change to this:

```
customers = await customerCollection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
```

You can understand why the first is not correct from the error message you got.

> Cannot await
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

calling the `GetResult` you block the thread that executes your code and you are waiting for the result of the thing you called the `GetResult`. The `GetResult` will return a `List<MongoDBApp.Models.CustomerModel>`. Apparently you can't await a generic result. While you can await the result of the `ToListAsync`, which is a task. In your case calling the `ToListAsync`, you get a `Task<List<MongoDBApp.Models.CustomerModel>>`. This can be awaited.

Comment: Ok I understand now, the above edit removes the error. But I've noticed when I try to assign the returned customers list , to an Observable collection of type Customer(using an extension method) it doesn't accept the new list type.

Comment: I get the following error: Error 6 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<MongoDBApp.Models.CustomerModel>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToObservableCollection' and no extension method 'ToObservableCollection' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<MongoDBApp.Models.CustomerModel>>' could be found

Comment: Make you method to return a `Task<ObservableCollection<T>>`.

Comment: ok so modify the extension method to return Task<ObservableCollection<T>> ? thanks